# Trouble with Running Javadoc

Tags: javadoc

My java textbook says that in order to document a class using javadoc, all I have to do is enter "javadoc SourceFile.java" into the command prompt. But when I do this it says "'javadoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

make sure the bin directory is added to your PATH environment correctly. 
http://thejarbar.org/views/tutorials/windows/PATH-Setup.xhtml

Comment: How do I do that? ... I'm noob. Taking Intro to Computer Science.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you check your bin directory and let me know if you see javadoc.exe there? Sometimes you may have to explicitly add it in your path.
2. Also make sure The SDK bin dir is in your path. Add it.
3. Is the SDK is installed? If not install it. (The VM is not sufficient.)

Comment: I have javadoc.exe located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin ... This is the SDK bin dir, isn't it?

Comment: yup. Then its no. 2 and your SDK bin dir isnt in your path.Follow the link given by jartender.